# How to plot clusters with binary matrix and coordinates?

Tags: plotting, graphics, cluster-analysis

I have to lists, xcor and ycor that contain the $x$-axis and $y$-axis coordinates of $N$ nodes. The nodes are divided into $C$ non overlapping clusters. The clustering information is provided in a binary matrix $Mmat$ of size $C\times N$, where $C$ is the number of clusters. If $M_{c,n}=1$, then node $n$ belongs to cluster $c$.

How can I show the clusters graphically?

xcor = {0.0667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.5000, 0.5000,
0.5000, 0.3000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.8333, 0.8333, 0.8333, 0.8333,
0.8333, 0.8333, 1.1667, 1.0667, 1.1667, 1.1667, 1.1067, 1.1667,
1.3000, 1.5000, 1.4000, 1.5000, 1.6000, 1.5000, 1.7333, 1.8333,
1.5333, 1.8333, 1.7333, 1.6333};

ycor = {0.1667, 0.4000, 0.8333, 1.1067, 1.5000, 1.6333, 0.1667, 0.4000,
0.8333, 1.1667, 1.5000, 1.8333, 0.1667, 0.5000, 0.8333, 1.1667,
1.5000, 1.7333, 0.1667, 0.5000, 0.7333, 1.1667, 1.4000, 1.8333,
0.1667, 0.5000, 0.8333, 1.1667, 1.5000, 1.8333, 0.1667, 0.5000,
0.7333, 1.1467, 1.5000, 1.6333};

Mmat = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

Answer (score 1):

```
xy = Transpose[{xcor, ycor}];
positions = Flatten[Position[#, 1]] & /@ Mmat;

lp = ListPlot[Extract[xy, List /@ positions], 
  PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkersThick", 
  PlotLegends -> Range[Length @ positions]]
```

[image]

```
lp2 = ListPlot[Extract[xy, List /@ positions]] /. 
   p_Point :> {Dynamic@EdgeForm[{Thin, CurrentValue["Color"]}], 
     Opacity[.2], Polygon@p[[1]]};

Show[lp, lp2]
```

[image]

```
lp3 = ListPlot[Extract[xy, List /@ positions]] /. 
   p_Point :> {Dynamic @ EdgeForm[{Thin, CurrentValue["Color"]}], Opacity[.2], 
    MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[Join @@ 
      (MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion@Circle[#, .05]] & /@  p[[1]])], 2]};

Show[lp, lp3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need!